# How to place button at only one Panorama page (screen)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, panorama-control

I'm using panorama UI in wp7.

I have several panorama screen each containing ListBox.
I want to add button only to one panorama page (together with ListBox), and when I move to another i don't won't to move the button on another page.
This button need to be above list box, with feature concerning only to this instance of list, and not another panorama screen.
Is this possible to achive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pivot control has Pivot Items, so you can add your button into only one Pivot Item

EDIT: inside pivot item (or panorama item) you have to use Grid to be able to have two rows, button in one and listbox in another

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
                <!--Pivot item one-->
                <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
                                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Row="0"></Button>
                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1"></ListBox>
                </Grid>

                </controls:PivotItem>

                <!--Pivot item two-->
                <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
                    <Grid/>
                </controls:PivotItem>
            </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: ups I misspelled the question, it's panorama not pivot. Sorry my bad :(

Comment: I think it's the same principle

Comment: @nemke: The same thing applies to a Panorama, it contains `PanoramaItem`s instead of `PivotItem`s

Comment: Yes you got my vote up(good trail), but when I add new PanoramaItem, it's new screen not the same where I was.

Comment: what you mean by screen? actually Panorama is one screen and it has items, which allows it to scroll right. Each item is separate container - this is what you need?

Comment: Maybe I need grid within Panorama, which can contain both listbox and button on the same panoramaItem. PanoramaItem would be grid. Maybe we shold go to chat room :)

Comment: I would say you need PanoramaItem which will contain Grid(2 rows), which will contain Button(1st row) and ListBox (2nd row)

Comment: I created with this grid. You can edit your answer in a way to be accepted. It's better that you write the answer than me. For the good karma :)

Comment: OK I edited the answer, I definitely do not want to harm my karma :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TitleTemplate` property for the `Panorama` control itself and then bind an existing static resource to it. For example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="header">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Pivot Control">
            </TextBlock>
            <Button Margin="0,0,800,0" Width="200" Content="Test"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

It is a pretty basic sample, but you can introduce custom binding.

Then you can reference the custom template in the control:

```
<controls:Panorama TitleTemplate="{StaticResource header}">
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Main"></controls:PanoramaItem>
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Second"></controls:PanoramaItem>
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Third"></controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

In a `Panorama` control, the button will be moving in the title anyway, so a better choice in your case would be the `Pivot` control where the title is not moving.